# Read cookies value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, asp-classic, inline

I am converting a classic ASP page to ASP.NET Vb . I get a line of code Where reading value form cookies .Below is the line of code where value is checking . My problem is that how can i convert this line of code in ASP.NET VB . I am doing inline code for conversion

```
<%if request.Cookies("parker")("id") <> "" then%><input name="agreement_acceptance_box" type="checkbox" value="yes"><%end if%>
```

Thanks for your answer . Its really very important for me

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is to read an array from the cookie? You don't provide much 'context', so I assume you have a Request object (it should be somewhere around ;-)):

```
If Not Request.Cookies("parker") Is Nothing AndAlso Not Request.Cookies("parker")("id") Is Nothing Then
   ...
```

More info on reading and writing cookies in VB.Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-7